# <T extends Object & E> vs <T extends E>

Tags: java, generics

The signature of [java.util.Collections.max](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29) looks like this:

> public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection collection);

From what I understand, it basically means that T must be both a  [java.lang.Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29) and a [java.lang.Comparable<? super T>>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html),

However, since every [java.lang.Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) is also an [java.lang.Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), what is the difference between the signature above and this below? :

> public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection collection);

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**To preserve binary compatibility**: It's completely described [here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ104). The second signature actually changes the return type of the method to `Comparable` and it loses the generality of returning an `Object`. The original signature preserves both.

Comment: Thanks for the link =) Btw are you aware of any tools to examine the erased signatures after compilation?

Comment: Not that I know of, but maybe [this](http://blog.xebia.com/2009/03/12/a-general-purpose-utility-to-retrieve-java-generic-type-values/) can give some clues on the topic. I also suggest reading the section on "Type Erasure" at Angelika Langer's Generics FAQ.

Comment: @Pacerier, yes, use "javap -s".