# How to Write a generic method to find the maximal element and invoke that method?

Tags: java, list, generics

While I was trying to solve exercise [from generics tutorial Q&A](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/QandE/generics-answers.html) My answers were slightly different

**My Answers**

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
    T max(List<? extends T> list, int begin, int end) //Option1

public static <T extends Comparable<T>>
    T max(List<? extends T> list, int begin, int end) //Option2
```

from quoted answer below

So My question is

- Option1 :Would it make any difference if `T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>` is replaced with `T extends Comparable<? super T>`. Isn't `extends Object` implicit ?
- Option2 :Would it make any difference if `Comparable<? super T>` is replaced with `Comparable<T>` ? if so How ?
- Eclipse code completion creates local variable `List<? extends Comparable<? super Comparable<? super T>>> list;` on Ctrl+1 `max(list, 1, 10);` which is bit lengthy. How to Define a classes (hierarchy) that extends `Comparable<? super T>` , create list and add instances to the list and invoke below method ? Basically I want to know how to invoke `max()` after adding class instances `A or B`  into a list where `class B extends A`

---

> Write a generic method to find the maximal element in the range
>   [begin, end) of a list.
>
> Answer:

```
import java.util.*;

public final class Algorithm {
    public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>>
        T max(List<? extends T> list, int begin, int end) {

        T maxElem = list.get(begin);

        for (++begin; begin < end; ++begin)
            if (maxElem.compareTo(list.get(begin)) < 0)
                maxElem = list.get(begin);
        return maxElem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Partially answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339338/t-extends-object-e-vs-t-extends-e

Comment: I don't really understand your 3rd question. Can you elaborate onto that a little?

Comment: For which method invocation does eclipse create that local variable? I don't see why would it do so. At least nested Comparable generic type is really not reasonable here.

Comment: I think I've already added the answer to your 3rd question. You can check the `Parent`, `Child` code there. I guess that is what you want.

Comment: @RohitJain It gets inserted by eclipse when you type `max(list, 1, 10);` and do ctrl1 and select 'create local variable list' . Yes you have answered 3rd Thanks:) . I was just bit confused when eclipse created that lengthy declaration

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Would it make any difference if `Comparable<? super T>` is replaced with `Comparable<T>` ? if so How ?

Remember that *Comparables* are always consumers, i.e., a `Comparable<T>` consumes `T` instances, so it should always be preferrable to use `Comparable<? super T>` instead of `Comparable<T>` (Quoting - **PECS**). It would make difference in case you are comparing a type whose super class implements a `Comparable<SuperType>`. Consider the following code:

```
class Parent implements Comparable<Parent> {
    protected String name;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Parent o) {
        return this.name.compareTo(o.name);
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public Child(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Now if you give your type parameter as `T extends Comparable<T>`, you won't be able to call that method for `List<Child>`, as *Child* does not implement `Comparable<Child>` but `Comparable<Parent>`:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(List<? extends T> list, int begin, int end) {
    ...
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Child> list = new ArrayList<Child>();
    max(list, 0, 2);  // Error with current method. Child does not implement Comparable<Child>
}
```

Hence the type parameter bounds should be `T extends Comparable<? super T>`.

Note that, you can't change your *Child* class to:

```
class Child extends Parent implements Comparable<Child>
```

because in that case, *Child* class would extend from different instantiation of same generic type, which is not allowed.

---

> Would it make any difference if `T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>` is replaced with `T extends Comparable<? super T>`. Isn't extends Object implicit ?

Well, there is a difference between the two bounds. In the 1<sup>st</sup> bound, the erasure of the type parameter is `Object`, whereas in the 2<sup>nd</sup> bound, the erasure is `Comparable`.

So, without `Object` bound, your code will compile to:

```
public static Comparable max(List list, int begin, int end)
```

The issue might come when you are generifying the legacy non-generic code. It's neccessary to give `Object` also as upper bound to avoid breaking the Byte Code compatibility. You can read more about it on this link: [Angelika Langer - Programming Idioms](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ104)

Comment: The erasure of a method only makes a difference for the input parameter types, not the return type, and the `Object` bound doesn't make a difference there:  it's still `max(List, int, int)`.  The `Object` is genuinely unnecessary here.

Comment: @LouisWasserman. Well, on first look I also thought the same, then I read on the link which I have added at the end. It's saying that it's necessary for maintaining byte code compatibility.

Comment: @RohitJain In fact `max(list, 0, 2);` will compile fine. but `Child child = max(list, 0, 2);` won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are more wildcards than necessary. I'll probably go with

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
    T max(List<T> list, int begin, int end)
```

An even more constrained version:

```
public static <T extends C, C extends Comparable<C>>
    T max(List<T> list, int begin, int end)
```

i.e. `T` must have a super type that is comparable to *itself*. For example `T` cannot be `Foo`

```
    class Foo implements Comparable<Object>
```

Foo does not make sense anyway; a Comparable can only be meaningfully compared to its own kind. The clause `C extends Comparable<C>` acknowledges that fact.