# Searching the maximal element in an array with generics

Tags: java, generics

Task:

> Write a generic method to find the maximal element in the range [begin, end) of a list.

Answer:

```
public final class Algorithm {
    public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>>
        T max(List<? extends T> list, int begin, int end) {

        T maxElem = list.get(begin);

        for (++begin; begin < end; ++begin)
            if (maxElem.compareTo(list.get(begin)) < 0)
                maxElem = list.get(begin);
        return maxElem;
    }
}
```

Can you explain how to use this method, please? And what is the difference with the following signature:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> 
    T max(List<? extends T> ar, int begin, int end) { ... }
```

Comment: I don't understand the *"Which types can i use?"* part of your question.

Comment: You can use any type that extends the Comparable interface, otherwise it's not guaranteed to have a `compareTo` function.

Comment: @BoristheSpider yup, just read the link you provided and deleted my comment... I learn something new every day

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a good question, it confuses even seasoned Java developers.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: I think this has the potential to be a good question. However, right now I don't think it is particularly well articulated (what does "Which types can i use?" even mean?) [I did not downvote BTW.]

Comment: The other part of the question is, I suppose, why `Comparable<? super T>` and not `Comparable<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume there are two questions here:

- Why the bounds `Object` is required
- Why to use `Comparable<? super T>` instead of `Comparable<T>`.

For the first question, it is not really required to give explicit `Object` bounds, but it may depend upon how you want the erasure of your method look like. With explicit `Object` bound, your type parameter will be erased to `Object`, and without that, it will be erased to `Comparable`. Most of the time, you won't find any need to give explicit bound, but this may be required for API compatibility as already explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19488357/1679863).

As for second question, using `Comparable<? super T>` is often a good idea, if you want to pass a list to `List<T>`, where `T` is comparable. Why? Suppose you have a class:

```
class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> { }
```

and a subclass:

```
class PartTimeEmployee extends Employee { }
```

and you want to pass a `List<PartTimeEmployee>` to a `List<T>`. It might seem straight-forward, and easy not before you realise that your `PartTimeEmployee` doesn't really implement a `Comparable<PartTimeEmployee>` but a `Comparable<Employee>`. So, what you do is, change the bounds of `T` to:

```
T extends Comparable<? super T>
```

.. and then you can pass a `List<PartTimeEmployee>`, as it satisfies the bound now.

The reason why you've to do this is to do with, *erasure* (Again?). Yes. On first seeing that error, you might jump off your chair and quickly make `PartTimeEmployee` comparable too by doing this:

```
class PartTimeEmployee extends Employee implements Comparable<PartTimeEmployee>
```

...but hey, you're doing wrong there. Java generics doesn't allow you to implement or extend from two different parameterized instantiation of same generic type. You're saying that, `PartTimeEmployee` implement both `Comparable<Employee>` and `Comparable<PartTimeEmployee>`. With this, you would have two methods in your `PartTimeEmployee`:

```
compareTo(PartTimeEmployee)
compareTo(Employee)
```

and after erasure, both of them will become:

```
compareTo(Object)
compareTo(Object)
```

and you've duplicate methods now. That is why it's illegal.

However in this case, since you have a `List<? extends T>` as parameter type, I think you might well do with `Comparable<T>`, because then when you pass a `List<PartTimeEmployee>`, `T` will be inferred as `Employee`, and hence will satisfy the bound.

Answer (score 1):

Problem: the difference between `public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>>` and `public static <T extends Comparable<T>>`

First part: why `extends Object`?

As very well explained in  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488357/why-is-t-bound-by-object-in-the-collections-max-signature), this is used for backwards compatibility reason with pre-1.5 APIs. So, if you don't have this problem, you can remove that.

Second part: why `Comparable<? super T>` and not `Comparable<T>`?

Let us take two classes `A` and `B`, with `B` inheriting `A`. You make both implement `Comparable`, but the logic for natural ordering is the same in `A` and `B`. As a result, you will write class definitions as:

```
public class A implements Comparable<A> {}

public class B extends A {}
```

Therefore, `B` implements `Comparable<A>`, not `Comparable<B>`. If it did the latter, you wouldn't be able to sort a `List<A>` where elements of the list were both of types `B` and `A`. Hence the `super`.

An example from the JDK: `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date`. The latter inherits the former. And you will see that `java.sql.Date` implements `Comparable<**java.util.Date**>`