# How to grok bounded wildcards in Java?

Tags: java, types, covariance, contravariance

In the [wikipedia article about co- and contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Use-site_variance_annotations_.28wildcards.29) there is an example use case and then an explanatory sentence describing what the type declaration means. I find this extremely useful. After reading the explanation a few times, I feel that I understand what it says.

```
<T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<T> coll);
```

> The bounded wildcard `? super T` conveys the information that `max` calls only contravariant methods from the Comparable interface.

Can somebody explain in a similar language, what the type declaration on the of the `andThen()` function in the `java.util.function.Consumer` `@FunctionalInterface` means:

```
public interface Consumer<T> {
    void accept(T t);
    default Consumer<T> andThen(Consumer<? super T> after) {
```

e.g.

> The bounded wildcard `? super T` conveys the information that `andThen` .... ?

---

And I have a secondary question: How can I find out myself, what such a type declaration means? E.g. in first example above from the `java.util.Collections` util class: How are the type bounds of a class - T - able to convey information about what the methods of T are doing? Can anybody point me to the relevant paragraphs in the Java language specification for this?

Comment: Last question is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488357/why-is-t-bounded-by-object-in-the-collections-max-signature).

Comment: And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) might answer the rest.

Comment: The word is "grok", not "grock".

Comment: Ok, thanks for the link shmosel. I removed the last question, as it is indeed answered there already.

However, for the first question it would be great to get the blanks filled in and I would love to get a pointer to the relevant part of the Java Language Spec for the second question.

Thanks for the spelling aid Lew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible answer to the first question:

```
public interface Consumer<T> {
    void accept(T t);
    default Consumer<T> andThen(Consumer<? super T> after) {
```

> The bounded wildcard `? super T` conveys the information that `andThen` takes Consumers of `T` or supertypes of `T`, aka. *contravariant* Consumers, as arguments.

---

Possible answer to the secondary question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2501513

Basically - completely independent of generics (!) - [method return return types are *inherently* "covariant"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#d5e13595) (assumed to be "producers") in the Java language. If overriding a method in a child class, you can always declare a more specific return type.

Method arguments are of course also "covariant" - you can only pass more specific objects than the method signature specifies. But on subclasses, although the method is technically [not overriden for non-parametric arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) - adhering to the [Liskov_substitution_principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) - it often makes sense to declare "contravariant" argument types in child classes, which - if the name and other arguments are equal - "overloads" the methods in the parent class. "Static" (reference-type-governed) method dispatch will then ensure that the (less specific) child method is called wins. Method arguments are assumed to be "consumed" and then PECS applies. Anyhow, for generic parameters, [bridge methods are generated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html#bridgeMethods) and it is all a bit more hairy. But we will [get](https://ideone.com/3YAkYS) [there](https://ideone.com/nAzAQt).