# Declaration of Comparable interface

Tags: java, generics

When the `Comparable` interface was made generic, the declaration became

```
interface Comparable<T>
```

Really it should be something like

```
interface Comparable<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

It makes no sense for the `T` to not extend `Comparable` because implementors must ensure that

```
a.compareTo(b)
```

and

```
b.compareTo(a)
```

always have opposite signums.

I have always assumed that the reason for getting the declaration "wrong" was something to do with the problems of generifying an existing interface, but I can't really explain it.

Does anyone have any insights?

Comment: It's not a "requirement of the interface", it's an implementation requirement. Which means you **should** do it, but you don't **have to** do it.

Comment: @Nathan I've changed the wording to "implementors must ensure that" because these are the exact words used in the docs.

Comment: I deleted my answer since recursive generic types are allowed in Java, I must of been thinking of something else. But one thing to point out is that the current definition allows for one-way relations.

Comment: I think you're right about the compatibility concern. Your version would produce `int compareTo(Comparable c)` after type erasure, which wouldn't be binary compatible with `int compareTo(Object o)`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488357/why-is-t-bounded-by-object-in-the-collections-max-signature

Comment: @shmosel Ah yes that's it. I think it's coming back to me now. I bet this is a duplicate. I'll close if I can find it.

Comment: What about `Comparable<T extends Object & Comparable<T>>`? Wouldn't that solve the problem?

Comment: @shmosel Yes it would (I think), but maybe they thought that was getting ridiculous. If you have to have the wrong declaration for compatability reasons, it might as well be wrong but simple.

Answer (score 3):

> Really it should be something like
>
> `interface Comparable<T extends Comparable<T>>`

But that doesn't really give you anything that you don't get with `interface Comparable<T>`.

You mention the thing about `a.compareTo(b)` and `b.compareTo(a)`, but note that your declaration (`interface Comparable<T extends Comparable<T>>`) doesn't actually ensure that if `a.compareTo(b)` is valid, that `b.compareTo(a)` compiles. If `a` is `Comparable<T>`, `a.compareTo(b)` requires that `b` be `T`, which is also `Comparable<T>`, so `b.compareTo()` takes a `T`. That doesn't prove that `b.compareTo(a)` works, as `a` is a `Comparable<T>`. As a case in point, consider `class Foo implements Comparable<Foo>`, and `class Bar implements Comparable<Foo>`. If `a` is of type `Bar` and `b` is of type `Foo`, then with your declaration of `Comparable`, `a.compareTo(b)` compiles but `b.compareTo(a)` doesn't compile (which is also the same thing that happens with the original declaration of `Comparable`). To have a bound that guarantees that when `a.compareTo(b)` works, that `b.compareTo(a)` also works, you would need to have something like `interface Comparable<T extends Comparable<Comparable<T>>>`, but that would be a useless interface because nobody has a `T` that is comparable to `Comparable<T>`.

More fundamentally, the purpose of adding a bound in Generics is to allow you to compile something that wouldn't compile, or would require a cast, without the bound. Remember, Java checks that code is type-safe at compile-time -- it will only allow you to compile something it knows is possible with the types declared at compile-time (unless you add explicit casts, in which case you take responsibility for the correctness of the conversion). So adding a bound will not increase type-safety -- with or without the bound, the Java compiler will only compile code that is provably type-safe (except for explicit casts or raw type conversions). The difference that a bound makes is that by adding constraints, it allows Java to accept *more* code as type-safe, because the constraints allow Java to deduce the correctness where it wasn't able to before. So a bound should only be added when it will allow you to compile something you couldn't without the bound, or would need to add explicit casts without the bound. Otherwise, what's the point of adding complexity for no benefit?

Here, you are not going to find any realistic use cases of code that would compile with your declaration of `Comparable` but would not compile with the original declaration. The only realistic use cases I've seen where a declaration `interface Foo<T extends Foo<T>>` would allow something to compile that wouldn't with `interface Foo<T>` is in something like the Builder pattern, where `Foo<T>` has a method that returns a `T`, and since we know that `T` is a subtype of `Foo<T>`, we can go from a `Foo<T>` to a `Foo<T>` and chain these operations, without knowing the specific type of `T`. But this is not the case with `Comparable` -- `Comparable` doesn't have a method that returns `T`.

If you have a class or method that takes in a comparable type that it needs to sort or order, it is going to have to be a generic method or class that requires the type be comparable to itself (e.g. `class SortedList<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` or `<T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T>)`). No bound in the declaration of `Comparable` can ensure that the type is comparable to itself.

If someone decides to write a class where a type is comparable to something completely unrelated (even something that is not `Comparable`), then that's fine from a type-safety point of view. Yes, you pointed out that it probably violates the documentation of `.compareTo()`, but that is a code behavior issue, not a type-safety issue. Their class will probably not be very useful because it will not satisfy the bounds of most places which use `Comparable`, which will likely have bounds that require that the type be comparable to itself. If there is a place that takes `Comparable` that doesn't have a bound requiring the type to be comparable to itself, then they can use their class there, but that is still type-safe, because the fact that the place didn't require the type to be comparable to itself means that its own code doesn't rely on that fact to compile safely (or they used explicit casts in which case they take responsibility for the correctness). In any case, that someone could potentially write a (mostly useless and maybe violates documentation) class that is comparable to something not comparable doesn't affect your ability to write your own class that is comparable to itself, and there is no type-safety reason to add any bounds.